# Ruby Change Join ON fields

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have a query that i run run Ruby and i am trying to change what fields that the 2 tables are joining ON

I want to have to do a query like this:

```
Select * from Teamplayers join Liveplayers On Nid = Live_Player_id
```

What have in Ruby right now is:

```
Teamplayer.joins(:liveplayer).where(:teamid => 1).all
```

This out puts the query of

```
Select * from Teamplayers join Live_players on Live_players.id = Teamplayer.live_player_id
```

My problem is that id and live_player_id are not the 2 fields that should be matching, it should by Nid(from live_players) and live_player_id(from teamplayers)

can someone help me with this? Is it a relation thing or a bad query?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the join like the following:

```
Teamplayer.joins('LEFT JOIN Live_players ON Live_players.Nid = Teamplayers.live_player_id')
```

But your table names are confusing me, I don't know if I used the proper names/case ...

Comment: That did not quite work as the query it generate was `Select * from teamplayers from Teamplayers Live_players on Nid = live_player_id` As you can see it is missing the join